# c semaphore sem_post max value to 0

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I have a program where one thread runs a task, and when it can no longer run it based on a condition, it waits:

```
void thread1() { 
    while(...) { 
        if(can_do_stuff) { 
            //do stuff
        }
        else { 
            sem_wait(&sem);
        }
    }
}
```

This thread can be woken up by several other threads (each performing a separate task that can lead to a reason for thread1 to be woken up) by calling `sem_post`:

```
void threadx() { 
    while(...) { 
        if(need_thread1_to_run) { 
            sem_post(&sem);
        }
        else { 
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

However, the problem with this is that whenever thread1 calls `sem_wait`, it needs to wait, which basically means that the maximum value that the semaphore should have is 0. So ideally, if it was already at 0 and a thread called `sem_post`, the value would not change. Is there anyway to do this with semaphores in C? If not, is there another synchronization method in C that could do this better? I thought that the threads could call `sem_getvalue` before calling `sem_post` to see if the value was already 0, but that would not be thread safe and I think two threads could still both call `sem_post` at the same time. I also thought that condition variables could be a possibility, but those require a mutex and I don't really need a mutex for this, so I was hoping there was something simpler.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?  What's wrong with thread1 getting the semaphore again (and not waiting)?  If `can_do_stuff` is false, it will loop around until the semaphore count becomes zero, at which point it will wait for the next time the semaphore is posted.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @JS1 Oh, yeah. That's a good point. I guess I was thinking that I didn't want to waste CPU just looping through the while when I know that thread1 can't do anything. Plus, it's possible that the other threads could meet the condition a lot of times and call sem_post a lot, at which point thread1 would go through the while loop for a while until it got the value of the semaphore down to 0. I guess it's not a huge deal and wouldn't hurt anything, I was just hoping for something a little more elegant that would waste less CPU time.

Comment: It shouldn't take much cpu to decrement a semaphore's value down to zero.  The only problem would be if checking for work to do is expensive.  If you want, you could clear the semaphore like this: right after the `sem_wait`, you could put a loop of repeatedly calling `sem_trywait` until the semaphore value becomes zero.  But it probably won't make a difference in terms of cpu usage.

Comment: @JS1 checking to see if there's work to do is not expensive, it's just a comparison of two ints: "`x <= y`". I guess I'll just do it this way. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way to be doing this. Thanks for the help!